# Magento 2.1.5: Product Widget for Homepage - Not Working

Tags: magento2, database, widgets, magento2.1.5

I am facing the following issue when creating a condition to show products on the homepage using the widgets in the content manager. I am running 2.1.5 and have manually checked the files for which there was a similar issue occurring for previous version (see file locations below). All three files are up-to-date with the fix but I am still facing this issue in Magento 2.1.5.

FYI, I have also done reindexing, clean and flushed the cache, as well as static content deploy.

> Error filtering template: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054
>   Unknown column 'e.b_homepage' in 'where clause'

Query was:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT e.entity_id) 
FROM 
    `catalog_product_flat_1` AS `e` 
    INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index`
    ON 
            cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id
        AND     cat_index.store_id='1' 
        AND     cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4)
        AND     cat_index.category_id='2'
    INNER JOIN
        `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index`
    ON
        price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id
        AND price_index.website_id = '1'
        AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0
WHERE (((IFNULL(`e`.`entity_id`, 0) IN (SELECT `catalog_category_product`.`product_id` FROM `catalog_category_product` WHERE (category_id IN ('42')))) AND(IFNULL(`e`.`b_homepage`, 0) = '1') ))
```

> /vendor/magento/module-catalog-widget/Model/Rule/Condition Combine.php
>
> Product.php
>
> /vendor/magento/module-catalog-widget/Test/Unit/Model/Rule/Condition
>   CombineTest.php

Answer (score 2):

Solved: In regards to the attribute giving the error, I did not select the settings under 'Use in Product Listing' to 'Yes'. After I selected 'Yes' and did complete reindex the widget worked with the two conditions.